# Cannot Centre FontAwesome Icon within circle

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I am trying to centre a FontAwesome Icon within a circle button but I cannot get it to work ( the icon keeps appearing above the circle as seen in the image

[image]

My HTML is as followed:

```
    <div class="socials">
        <div class="socialbuttons">
            <a class="fa-brands fa-instagram" href="https://instagram.com" target="_blank"></a>
            <a class="fa-brands fa-github" href="https://instagram.com" target="_blank"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And My CSS:

```
.socialbuttons{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.fa-brands{
    text-decoration: none !important;
    color: white !important;
    background: #1a1a1a;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    flex-direction: column;
    display: inline-block;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 100%;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

I have already attempted many different align methods, resizing width and height, moving the width and height within the div css but still nothing

Comment: I see no circles in your image - UNLESS I click it. No idea why (Chrome quirk?) but I suggest you change your sample code + the image to become more "readable", with circles that have a very distinct color and not *very dark gray on a black background*.

Answer (score 0):

Change the links from `display: inline-block` to `display: inline-flex`

```css
a.fa-brands {
  margin: 2em;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  color: white !important;
  background: #1a1a1a;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  flex-direction: column;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.5.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="socials">
  <div class="socialbuttons">
    <a class="fa-brands fa-instagram" href="https://instagram.com" target="_blank"></a>
    <a class="fa-brands fa-github" href="https://instagram.com" target="_blank"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```